# Convert existing ASP.NET web site from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, https

I am developing a website and thinking about whether it will be published as HTTP or HTTPS. Is there any code difference between HTTP and HTTPS website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use seem code for both `HTTP` and `HTTPS` application . For HTTPS you need to configure the `SSL certificate` on your server.

Here is the brief details about the server setup
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure#Server_setup

For certificate configuration following link can be helpful
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx